# A mixture of conjugate priors is conjugate

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mixture-distribution, conjugate-prior

I want to prove that a mixture of conjugate priors is itself conjugate. It does not look difficult, but I'm still a bit unsure when manipulating probabilities, especially in a Bayesian context. Is this proof correct?

Consider the following prior.
$$ 
p(\theta) = \sum_k p(z=k)p(\theta | z=k)
$$
The posterior after observing $D$ is
$$
p(\theta | D) = \frac{p(\theta, D)}{p(D)}
$$
By the law of total probability
$$
\frac{p(\theta, D)}{p(D)} = \frac{\sum_k p(z=k)p(\theta ,D |z=k)}{p(D)}
$$
which by the chain rule of probability equals
$$
 \frac{\sum_k p(z=k) p(D |z=k) p(\theta | D,z=k)}{p(D)}
$$
Since $\frac{p(z=k) p(D|z=k)}{p(D)} = p(z=k|D)$
$$
p(\theta | D) = \sum_k p(z=k|D) p(\theta | D, z=k) \mbox{ Q.E.D.}
$$

Comment: Looks okay to me. Why don't you try to write a program for a dataset. But it looks fine.